# Linq - Order by StartsWith then Contains

Tags: linq

Say i have 3 customer names:

```
Microsoft
Another customer also called Microsoft
A third customer called Microsoft
```

Now if i query the customers like this...

```
var q = (from cust in db.Cust
                    where cust.Name.Contains("Microsoft")
                    orderby cust.Name ascending
                    select cust)
```

...i get this order:

```
A third customer called Microsoft
Another customer also called Microsoft
Microsoft
```

What i want is to get Microsoft first, based on the fact that it starts with "Microsoft".

Changing Contains to StartsWith of course leaves me with 1 result instead of 3.

Could this be done in a single query?

Comment: I don't think so, you almost need to use Full Text Queries with weighting.

Comment: @Sam - I abandoned full text search. It gave me a headache when using white spaces in search.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Maybe

```
var q = (from cust in db.Cust
                    where cust.Name.Contains("Microsoft")
                    orderby cust.Name.IndexOf("Microsoft"),
                             cust.Name.Length ascending
                    select cust)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could order by the percentage of the match.

```
orderby "Microsoft".Length * 1.0 / cust.Name.Length
```

This would yield 100% for just *Microsoft* and much less for the other matches.

Comment: aMicrosoft gets same weight as MicrosoftB with such approach

Comment: Interesting solution. Need to add descending though. Thumbs up!