# OrderBy search results that startswith searcch word then by results that contains search word

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting, generics

I have an object like this:

```
  public class MyObject
{
    public List<string> Names { get; set; }
    // other props
}
```

and I have a filtered List like this :

```
   var freeText = "comm";
    var list = new List<MyObject>(); // Initialized

    var searchResult = list.Where(o =>
        o.Names.Any(n => n.ToLower().StartsWith(freeText.ToLower())) ||
        o.Names.Any(n => n.ToLower().Contains(freeText.ToLower())));
```

and it's working fine but, what I'm trying to do is to get the search results ordered by
starts with first then by contains.

ex:

```
Obj 1 {Names : [ "free communication" ,"some name"]},
Obj 2 { Names : ["communcation Center", "whatever"]}
```

I want the result to be [Obj2, Obj1].

I tried to orderBy index of freeText but it doesn't seem to work on an array/list of string.
I tried to ulter the solution at [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004407/linq-order-by-startswith-then-contains) so it works on array instead of string but it didn't work.
any idea how to to this?

Comment: A tip: to avoid needlessly allocating two whole new strings just to check for StartsWith or Contains, use `n.StartsWith(freeText, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)` instead of `n.ToLower().StartsWith(freeText.ToLower())`

Comment: It's Unsupported in MongoDb filters.

Comment: This question was about filtering an in-memory List (`IEnumerable`), not a remote database (`IQueryable`). They're quite different, and indeed I've yet to see an `IQueryable` filter that supports the `StringComparison` enum. Those I have used don't support `ToLower()` either

Comment: MongoDb Driver's Generic Find takes a filter parameter as an  Expression<Func<TDocument,bool>> and it supports ToLower, Equals, StartsWith, Contains ..etc but some operations are not supported, StringComparison enum is one of them. The ordering is taking place later in an In-memory list and that was what I asked about. Your tip is totally correct in case of filtering was in an In-memory List. So thanks of the tip :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a simple scoring mechanism where you'll capture two flags (`startsWith` and `contains`) and use those flags both for filtering and for sorting:

```
var result = list.Select(item => new
{
    item,
    startsWith = item.Names.Any(n => n.ToLower().StartsWith(freeText.ToLower())),
    contains = item.Names.Any(n => n.ToLower().Contains(freeText.ToLower())),
})
.Where(item => item.startsWith || item.contains)
.OrderByDescending(item => item.startsWith)
.ThenByDescending(item => item.contains)
.Select(x => x.item);
```